# If $p$ is an odd prime and $(a/p)=1$ then $a$ is not a primitive root mod $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

prove the following :

If $p$ is an odd prime and $(a/p)=1$ then $a$ is not a primitive root mod $p$.

Could you please help me with that how can I do it by using Euler Criterion any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is square mod $p$, then $a=b^2$ and so $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=b^{p-1}=1$.

Therefore, the order of $a$ is at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and so $a$ cannot have order $p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a/p)=1$ (Legendre symbol) then $(a^k/p)=(a/p)^k=1$ for all integers $k$ (Legendre symbol is multiplicative). If $a$ were a primitive root,
what would that mean?

Comment: If a were a primitive root mod p then a^k ≡ 1 (mod p)

Comment: how can I solve the question it by using Euler Criterion?